# Sitting water after overnight cure

Tags: cement

I placed 4, 4x4s in 5 gal buckets to hang a shade sail. I used 1 gal of water per bag. This was last night at 7pm. 75°. 50's overnight. 10am, 2 still have water in them and the other 2 still feel soft. Almost like clay. Did we add too much water? Help please.

Thank you

Comment: How much water did the bags say to use?  Did you mix the cement well?

Comment: 4 five gallon containers are not much of an anchor for sails.  You would be amaze a what a bit of wind can pick up.

Comment: I used 50 lb bags and it calls for a gallon of water. I put the post in the 5 gallon bucket, leveled it, added most of the quikrete, added most of the water, and mixed a little. Then I added the rest of the cement and water. You can mix in a wheel barrel or something, but it says on the bag  to do it this

Comment: I know they aren't that big of an anchor for a 10x13 sail shade, but my neighbor didn't want cement in the ground.  I did add some wire rope supports on each post though. As of right now, there is no more water in the buckets.

Comment: I hope these are temporary anchors only, and the sail will be removed when unused.

Comment: attach the sail to the buckets with twine, small zip ties,  or 60lbs test fishing line to avoid unpleasantness.

Comment: Can I add a picture? Like I said, this is my first couple days on here and I'm still not sure how to do things. I lifted and tightened the shade sail today and it came out pretty well. 8/10. It seems safe enough for medium winds. I still wish I could've put the posts in the ground. As long as the neighbor is happy, I'm happy.

Comment: what does the neighbor have to do with anything?

Answer (score 3):

All is vague here, because you provided very little detail such as the product, or the size of the bags - but assuming you used 80 lb bags of [Quickcrete](https://quikrete.com/athome/video-mixing-concrete-hand.asp), or a similar product, that was **at least 1 quart** too much water per the linked page. If you used **smaller** bags, such as the 60, 50 or 40 lb sizes they also sell, **it's worse.**

If the product was old and the bags had partly hardened, there's a further problem available (concrete mix that has set in the bag won't set again, even if you break it up so it vaguely resembles a powder.)

*I would agree with the comment that that's not much of an anchor for a sail of any size, so it might just make battering rams for the wind to flail about with....*